# Custom formatter in jqGrid which calls jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid with a custom formatter that returns two checkboxes:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $("#gridAgenda").jqGrid({
    ...
    colModel: [
        ...,
        "asiste",
        ...
    ],
    colModel:[
        ...,  
        {name:'asiste',formatter:asisteFormater},
        ...
    ]
    ...
});
}
function asisteFormater (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
    return "Sí<input type='checkbox' id='asisteSi'/> No<input type='checkbox' id='asisteNo'/>";
}

$("#asisteSi").click(function () {
    ...
}
```

But I want to call a jQuery function when any of the two checkboxes are checked, to evaluate which one was checked and calling an ajax function. I think the problem is, that asisteSi does not exist until the jqGrid is created, so I cannot do this.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put the callback attachment into the `gridComplete` option of the grid definition, just like this:

```
$('#gridAgenda').jqGrid({
    ...
    gridComplete: function () {
        $("#asisteSi").click(function () {
            // do your deed
        });
    }
});
```

**Supplemental**

By the way, if there are multiple rows in the grid, you should not use `asisteSi` as your id, because it won't be unique in the page, and that causes undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I've solved this way:

```
gridComplete: function () {
        var rowData = $("#gridAgenda").getRowData();             
        for (var i = 0; i < rowData.length; i++) 
        {               
            var asisteSi="#asisteSi"+rowData[i].id;
            var asisteNo="#asisteNo"+rowData[i].id;             
            $(asisteSi).click(function(){           
                var actualSi = "#"+this.id;
                var actualNo = actualSi.replace("asisteSi","asisteNo");                 
                if($(actualSi).prop('checked')){
                    $(actualNo).prop('checked', false);                 
                }
                //TODO:llamada ajax
            });             
            $(asisteNo).click(function(){           
                var actualNo = "#"+this.id;
                var actualSi = actualNo.replace("asisteNo","asisteSi");
                if($(actualNo).prop('checked')){
                    $(actualSi).prop('checked', false);                     
                }
                //TODO:llamada ajax                 
            });
         }
}
```

The problem was that $(asisteSi) had the last value when do click, so I had to get the current Id